# Is there anyway to install Kali Linux into your external SSD, and make it bootable on M1 Chip Macbook Pro?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, dual-boot, macos, ssd

I am currently trying to install Kali Linux into my SSD card, and have it boot on M1 Chip macbook pro. Is there anyway to make that possible?

Comment: why? ... kali is not meant to be installed

Answer (score 1):

Quote from kali linux's website

> Newer Mac hardware (e.g. T2/M1 chips) do not run Linux well, or at
> all. This is true for Linux in general, not just Kali Linux.

So the answer is, probably no. There is *some* M1 support in the latest Kali release. Run it as a VM with VMWare Fusion on a Mac. This is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think that you will find a better solution than to run it in a virtual environment. Maybe in a few months but certainly not in the next couple of weeks.

Just keep in mind, you can still "pass through" nearly any USB device like a WLAN stick etc. to your VM (Virtual Machine) so there is no need for a native (bare-metal) setup. For stuff which requires a lot of power like Aircrack or Hashcat, I dont think that a M1 system would be a great solution at all.